# How to prevent dial up networking connection window from coming up on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dial-up

I have PPP over Ethernet connection at home, so I have a dial up connection set up which comes up every time when I log in, so I can connect to the net by clicking on it. This works fine, but now I got a router which does the connection automatically, so there is no need for the dial up networking connecting window to come up.

Nevertheless it comes up everytime when I log in regardless of the living net connection already established by the router. It does not cause any error I only have to cancel the dialog, but it's a nuisance and I can't find any setting to make it stop.

Of course, I could remove the networking connection altogether, but I'd rather keep it, so I don't have to create it again if sometimes I need to connect to the net directly without the router.

Is there a way to stop the connection dialog from coming up without removing the networking connection?

Comment: Just remove the dial-in connection from your windows profile.

Comment: And how can I do that? I see only delete connection, but I don't want to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open '*Internet Options*' in your '*Control Panel*', go to the '*Connections*' tab and check the radio button '*Never dial a connection*'.

Answer (score 3):

Its very easy to do just open the **Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center**. Now select the **Change Adapter setting** from the left panel. Now the default connection should be tick marked with a green button and right click on it. Now right click on it and select **Cancel as Default connection**.

[image]

**Edit in response of comment**

If it is not set default there then you have to launch the **Internet explorer** and now open the **Tools>Internet Option** and select the **connection** tab. You can also go to **Internet connections** through control panel. Now here you have three option:

> **1:** Never Dial A connection
>   **2:** Dial whenever a connection is not available
>   **3:** Always dial my default connection

You have to select the first option and click on **apply**.

[image]

Comment: It's not a default connection. I have a "set as default connection" item in the menu where you have the "cancel as..." item

Comment: @Tom updated the answer check it...